# OPC Connection for Alarm and Event

Tags: opc

I am trying to connect to opc for Alarm and Event. I can connect and read data from opc with opcname.da

but I need to connect opcname.ae and read events from there. I look for sample solution but I can't find.

I am using opcautomation.dll.

then I tried with opcnetapi.dll with below code;

```
            if (mserver.IsConnected)
            {
                groupState.Name = "Subscription";
                groupState.Active = false;
                groupState.BufferTime = 0;
                groupState.MaxSize = 0;
                groupState.ClientHandle="0x0205A578";
                group = (Opc.Ae.Subscription)ConnectedOPCServer.CreateSubscription(groupState);
                group.Refresh();                  
            }
```

but it is giving error on "group = (Opc.Ae.Subscription)ConnectedOPCServer.CreateSubscription(groupState);" systemnullreferenceExeption.

I thnik ı need to add same tags to group. but how I can do?

Comment: You should specify which OPC toolkit or library you are using.

Comment: I am using opcautimation.dll